# Obtain values coming along with the url

Tags: php, html

I want to obtain values coming along with the URL(actually they are seen due to `GET` request unlike `POST`, if there is in the `POST` way I wish to learn it as well) as seen in the below image. We don't know what value will come until it's clicked. Additionally, is there a way to transfer some payload from one page to another in PHP?

@Edit: I have found a way via `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` but it ruins non-english characters like  `3=Papatya+Sar%C4%B1` for `Papatya Sarı`

[image]

Comment: (Didn't downvote) You use $_POST to see them for POST requests?

Comment: @nice_dev I have edited the question to show what I've done so far.

Comment: `$_GET, $_REQUEST` gives you an array of request parameters and you might have to run `urldecode`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, however, with the guidance of the commenters I have ended up with the following.

```
 #for GET requests
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
     echo $key . " " . $value;
}
```